# Cypress: How to add loop based on the array length?

Tags: arrays, loops, cypress

I have this code where i get **'ul[class="menu"] > li'** get there text and convert it to arrays 'list'

```
    it('List to array', () => {
        const list = []
        cy.get('ul[class="menu"] > li').children()
            .each(($ele) => {
            list.push($ele.text().toString().trim())
          })
          .then(() => {
            cy.get('ul[class="menu"] > li').should('contain',list[0])
            cy.log(list[0])
          })

})
```

Now i want to add a loop until it finished my array in list that will assert (should) based on my last code because the length of list is constantly changing and i don't want a repeated code

How can i achieved this?

Comment: What do you want to assert? Can you give example please.

Comment: Base on the array of list i want to compare the text inside the 'ul[class="menu"]' and it should be equal to array of list and it will loop until it finished the length of list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at docs for [each()](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/each#Arguments), Cypress passes in each element and also it's index.

Use the index to get the value from the list.

```js
cy.get('ul.menu > li')     // same as 'ul[class="menu"] > li'
  .each(($el, index) => {
    expect($el.text()).to.eq(list[index])
  })
```

Comment: The [index] what i looking for. Thank you for this!